# Saving a web page

Tags: html, web, web-scraping

I want to periodically scrape my blog for links and archive the pages I link to, lest they be lost forever in the sands of time. What's the best way to save them such that when I later want to view them, I can see them as they would have appeared if I'd clicked the link when they'd still been up?

Many web browsers seem to have this functionality bound to Ctrl/Cmd-S. Is there a good way to do it programmatically?

Comment: http://www.archive.org/web/web.php

Answer (score 1):

you don't talk about technology stack so maybe anything goes.

It looks to me like phantomjs might be what you're looking for, it's a headless webkit so can scrape your site and write it out as a PDF.

http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Rendering

Comment: I'd also like to save things like videos, js/css resources, images, interactive elements. I kind of want a snapshot of everything the browser would know about if it loaded the page -- so in 10 years' time I can come back to it and see it just how I see it today.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [ifttt](http://ifttt.com)

Make a task to let ifttt periodically scrape your post(maybe by RSS) then do something to save it. You can choose to send an email about the content, or send it to Evernote. I'm using the second way.

Comment: I'd like to save the page as close to its original appearance as possible, including images, JavaScript and CSS files, etc. There are many linked documents which get loaded separately from the main HTML.